# Laravel required if

Tags: validation, laravel-7

I have the field that appears if option `VK` is selected.

```html
<select id="contact" name="contact" type="text">
    <option disabled selected value="sas">sas</option>
    <option value="VK">VK</option>
    <option value="Viber">Viber</option>
    <option value="WhatsApp">WhatsApp</option>
</select>

<input class="musician_input_div form_control" 
    id="contact_method_vk" name="contact_method_vk" 
       placeholder="id" style="display:none;" type="text" type="text"/>
```

The field is required and if I choose `viber`, this field will be hidden and the form will not send. How do I adjust validator?

```php
$this->validate($request, [
//(if option VK is selected){
    'contact' => 'required',
}
]);
```

Comment: do you mean `contact_method_vk` is required when `VK` is selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand your question correctly. All you need to do is like this.

```php
$this->validate($request, [
          'contact_method_vk' => 'required_if:contact,VK'
]);
```

This will make `contact_method_vk` is required when `VK` is selected.

**Note: some explanation about required_if. `required_if:anotherfield,value`**: The field under validation must be present and not empty if the anotherfield field is equal to value.